# Moment.js - Converting UTC To Eastern Time

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, aws-lambda

I am using `moment-timezone.js` in order to convert UTC time to `America/New_York` via node.js. I am doing this like so:

```
var moment  = require('moment-timezone');
moment.tz.add('America/New_York|EST EDT|50 40|0101|1Lz50 1zb0 Op0');

var now    = new Date().toISOString();
now = moment(now).tz("America/New_York").toDate();
```

This seems to work fine on my local machine, but when I run it on AWS Lambda, the `now` time is still being outputted as UTC. 
Am I doing something wrong here? I really don't want to have to use an API just to get the accurate New York time. Daylight savings is the biggest challenge here. Thanks!

Comment: What time zone is your local machine using? Where is the code that is outputting the date? I'm pretty sure once you call toDate() you are losing any timezone information.

Comment: Yes you are right, calling toDate() uses the original, pre-moment date object. I figured out the solution, and will post in a bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way I figured this out was to do:

```
var now = ((moment(Date.now()).utcOffset('-0500').format('x'));
//Parse it into native JS object: 
now = new Date(parseInt(now));
```

I want to point something out though that I hope will save someone the days of time this burdened me for. My main issue was that Amazon Lambda was providing time in UTC, no matter what I was doing. The fix for this issue was to simply set the Node TZ environment variable:

```
process.env.TZ = 'America/New_York';
```

Comment: will this handle daylight changes also?

Comment: Wow nice trick!. I'm pretty sure that daylight changes will be handled by moment if you choose an IANA zone like `America/New_York`, @Shamseer but not a static offset like `-0500` (as per above).

Answer (score 10):

First, install [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) and install all of the timezones by using `timezone-with-data.js` or [specifically only load the timezones you need](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

If you have a date that you know is in UTC and want to convert it to Eastern time, use the `moment.utc()` function to actually parse the UTC datestring. Then when you call `.tz()` on it will properly convert:

```
moment.utc(date_string).tz("America/New_York")
```

If you simply do `moment(date_string).tz("America/New_York")` the time gets parsed in your local timezone by default, and it will not adjust the date.

Answer (score 4):

Eastern Standard Time (EST) is 5 hours behind Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

With moment.js, you can subtract 5 hours from UTC timezone.

```
moment.utc().subtract(5, 'hours').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS")
```

Or

If you are willing to add another library like `moment-timezone`. You can just use:

```
moment().tz("America/New_York").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS")
```

Comment: Eastern **Standard** Time is 5 hours behind UTC. But Eastern **Daylight** Time is 4 hours behind UTC. So if you just subtract 5 hours, the time will be wrong during Daylight Saving Time. OP specifically pointed out "Daylight savings is the biggest challenge here."